# Pass JSON with segue within an asynchronous subprocess(alamofire)

Tags: ios, swift2, alamofire

Hello stackoverflow fellows!

im trying to do a login with mysql in swift, so far i got my app to receive the info from the database, but now, i need it to be in the next view controller. As far as i read i need to override the prepareForSegue with the next view variables to receive the data and the current view variables, the things is that i can't or haven't figured out, how to override with variables within my asynchronous alamofire request, is there another way to segue with variables as arguments, or how should i handle the JSON objects in my alamofire to pass them to the next segue.

Here's my code:

```
    func login(){



    let url="http://primefitness.hostoi.com/scripts/read_user_ios.php"

    let user : String = usuario.text!
    let pass : String = password.text!
    var u : Bool = false
    var p : Bool = false

    Alamofire.request(.POST ,url,parameters: ["usuario":user]).responseJSON{

        request,response,result in

        switch result{

        case .Success(let perfil):

            let json = JSON(perfil)

            if let usuarioweb : String = json["usuario"].string{
                //print(usuarioweb)
                if user == usuarioweb{
                    u = true
                }
                else{
                    u = false
                }
            }
            if let passweb = json["password"].string{
                //print(passweb)
                if pass == passweb{
                    p = true
                }
                else{
                    p = false
                }
            }

            if u && p{
                if let activo : Bool = json["activo"].boolValue{

                    if activo {
                        JLToast.makeText("Usuario Correcto", duration: JLToastShortDelay).show()
                        //self.rutina(json, user: user)
                        //print(perf)
                        let url2="http://primefitness.hostoi.com/scripts/read_rutina_ios.php"

                        Alamofire.request(.POST ,url2,parameters: ["usuario":user]).responseJSON{

                            request,response,result in

                            switch result{

                            case .Success(let rutina):

                                let json = JSON(rutina)

                                if json["sinexito"] == "No Items Found"{
                                    JLToast.makeText("No existe rutina.", duration: JLToastShortDelay).show()
                                }
                                else{
                                    self.cargarNewView(JSON(perfil), rutina: json)
                                }


                            case .Failure(let data, let error):

                                JLToast.makeText("Error con la base de datos, intentelo de nuevo.", duration: JLToastShortDelay).show()
                                print("Fallido con error: \(error)")

                                if let data=data{

                                    print("Datos respondidos: \(NSString(data: data,encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))")

                                }

                            }

                        }


                    }
                    else{
                        JLToast.makeText("Usuario Inactivo, contacte a su administrador", duration: JLToastShortDelay).show()
                    }
                }

            }
            else{
                JLToast.makeText("Usuario/Contraseña Incorrecto", duration: JLToastShortDelay).show()
            }



        case .Failure(let data, let error):

            JLToast.makeText("Error con la base de datos, intentelo de nuevo.", duration: JLToastShortDelay).show()
            print("Fallido con error: \(error)")

            if let data=data{

                print("Datos respondidos: \(NSString(data: data,encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))")

            }

        }

    }

}//final login    

func cargarNewView(perfil: JSON,rutina: JSON){

    print(perfil)
    print(rutina)
    performSegueWithIdentifier("login", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

    if segue.identifier == "login"{
        let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! rutinaViewController
        destinationVC.prueba = "hola"//testing the override
    }

    // Create a new variable to store the instance of the next view controller

}
```

EDIT:

got the answer from Paulw11 and im adding the correct code for future references:

Add instance variables:

```
var perfil:JSON?
var rutina:JSON?
```

Assign the values to instance variables from a function receiving the request values:

```
    func cargarNewView(per: JSON,rut: JSON){

    perfil = per
    rutina = rut

    performSegueWithIdentifier("login", sender: self)
}
```

The override prepareForSegue as follows:

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

    if segue.identifier == "login"{
        let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! rutinaViewController
        destinationVC.perfil = perfil
        destinationVC.rutina = rutina


    }

    // Create a new variable to store the instance of the next view controller

}
```

Comment: You have a couple of options. 1 is to store the data you want to send in some instance properties so that you can access it in `prepareForSegue`  The other is to create a an object to store the data and pass an instance of that object as the `sender` in `performSegueWithIdentifier` so that, again, it is available in `prepareForSegue`

Comment: with stored properties you mean struct?

Comment: No, it would have to be a class because `performSegueWithIdentifier` takes  `AnyObject`, not `Any` so you can't use a struct

Comment: Or you could just use two String properties.  Or you could use a struct property and not pass it via the `sender`

Comment: Sorry @Paulw11 im not really following you, im totally new to swift and right now i wish its was as easy as .putExtra() like in android :(

Comment: You need to access your `perfil` and `rutina` values in `prepareForSegue` so that you can use them to set properties on your destination view controller. You have a couple of options.  One is to pass them via the `sender` argument to `performSegueWithIdentifier` but you have two values and one parameter so you would need to create an object that had two properties, assign the two values to those properties and then pass that object as `sender`, so you could access it in `prepareForSegue`.

Comment: The simpler option is to create two variable in your instance (so outside of the function) that you can set them in `cargarNewView` and access them in `prepareForSegue`

Comment: the simpler options is not an option, since Alamofire.request is an asynchronus request. and the global variables wont update until the process is done, ive tried that, I.E. first time i clic the button, the variables will be nil, if i go back and clic it again now i can access them, so i really need to pass them from within the alamofire request(as i did in android, my intent was called within the the volley request and put the response as putExtra)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90832/discussion-between-paulw11-and-inaki-pedroche-aramburu).